# Unble to access public class of Swift embedded framework in objective-c project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios9, embedded-framework

I have an issue regarding embedded framework.

I have developed a framework in swift language with minimum devlopment target iOS 9.0 and xcode 11.3.1.

I have successfully imported in objective c project which have minimum development target iOS 9.0, but unable to access public class and it's showing unknown type error.

Please suggest what I will do

Comment: Is this an issue with a specific Swift class or are you unable to import any class you've defined in Swift? My guess is it has something to do with how you've defined your Swift class (for example, it doesn't inherit from `NSObject`)

Comment: I bellive you need to manually copy the generated swift headers to your objective-c target. Perhaps this article will help: https://medium.com/@mail2ashislaha/swift-objective-c-interoperability-static-libraries-modulemap-etc-39caa77ce1fc

Comment: i am unable to import all public swift class and All public classes inherit from NSObject with @objc.